# How to screengrab current page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When you send feedback using the new Google Maps Beta, you have the option to send a screengrab of the page you're on.  Given that no Java alerts appear, I can only assume this is using JavaScript.

How would I take a screengrab of the page I'm on using JavaScript, like how Google Maps Feedback Service does?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try using a canvas element's [drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FCanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29)